# Arcball 3D camera

Tags: opengl, c++, camera, rotation

I have checked multiple threads before posting, but i havent been able to figure this one out.

Ok so i have been following this tutorial, but im not using glm, ive been implementing everything up until now, like lookat etc.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Arcball

So i can rotate with the click and drag of the mouse, but when i rotate 90º degrees around Y and then move the mouse upwards or donwwards, it rotates on the wrong axis, this problem is demonstrated on this part of the tutorial

> An extra trick is converting the rotation axis from camera coordinates
>   to object coordinates. It's useful when the camera and object are
>   placed differently. For instace, if you rotate the object by 90° on
>   the Y axis ("turn its head" to the right), then perform a vertical
>   move with your mouse, you make a rotation on the camera X axis, but it
>   should become a rotation on the Z axis (plane barrel roll) for the
>   object. By converting the axis in object coordinates, the rotation
>   will respect that the user work in camera coordinates (WYSIWYG). To
>   transform from camera to object coordinates, we take the inverse of
>   the MV matrix (from the MVP matrix triplet).

What i have to do acording to the tutorial is convert my axis_in_camera_coordinates to object coordinates, and the rotation is done well, but im confused on what matrix i use to do just that. 
The tutorial talks about converting the axis from camera to object coordinates by using the inverse of the MV. Then it shows these 3 lines of code witch i havent been able to understand.

```
glm::mat3 camera2object = glm::inverse(glm::mat3(transforms[MODE_CAMERA]) *       
glm::mat3(mesh.object2world));
glm::vec3 axis_in_object_coord = camera2object * axis_in_camera_coord;
```

So what do i aply to my calculated axis?, the inverse of what, i supose the inverse of the model view? So my question is how do you transform camera axis to object axis.
Do i apply the inverse of the lookat matrix?
My code:

```
if (cur_mx != last_mx || cur_my != last_my) {
    va = get_arcball_vector(last_mx, last_my);
    vb = get_arcball_vector( cur_mx,  cur_my);
    angle = acos(min(1.0f, dotProduct(va, vb)))*20;

            axis_in_camera_coord = crossProduct(va, vb);

    axis.x = axis_in_camera_coord[0];
    axis.y = axis_in_camera_coord[1];
    axis.z = axis_in_camera_coord[2];
    axis.w = 1.0f;

    last_mx = cur_mx;
    last_my = cur_my;
}
Quaternion q = qFromAngleAxis(angle, axis);
Matrix m;
qGLMatrix(q,m);

vi = mMultiply(m, vi);
up = mMultiply(m, up);

ViewMatrix = ogLookAt(vi.x, vi.y, vi.z,0,0,0,up.x,up.y,up.z);
```

Comment: EDIT Instead of a single R*T view matrix ive split it into 2 rotations one on the X axis and another on the Y axis (R*R*T). Also i was implementing quaternion rotation without setting my initial camera orientation..

Comment: You should post that as an answer for future visitors, and mark as the answer as well (please don't include "tags" like "resolved" in question titles).

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things a bit. You may check those answers: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26007/arcball-problems-with-udk/37242#37242 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603412/algorithm-3d-orbiting-camera-control-with-mouse-drag/21646259#21646259